# How to declare Module in Page to use IDE autocompletion In GEB?

Tags: autocomplete, dsl, geb, strong-typing, pageobjects

According to http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/modules.html#modules
Modules should be defined like this:

```
class ExamplePage extends Page {
    static content = {
        theModule { module ExampleModule }
    }
}
```

From Geb's Documentation:

> 16.2.2 Strong typing
>
> In order to gain improved authoring support, you must include types in
>   your tests and page objects. Additionally, you must explicitly access
>   the browser and page objects instead of relying on dynamic dispatch.

So:

```
HomePage homePage = browser.to HomePage
homePage.loginButton.click()
```

It's works fine for Pages, but can i find the way to have it with Modules aswell?
to have autocompletion here:

```
HomePage homePage = browser.to HomePage
homePage.loginFormModule. *autosuggestion here*
```

(where "loginFormModule" - is module of HomePage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stronger typing for module definitions has been recently added to master but hasn't been released yet. Basically the location of `module()` method has changed so that now IntelliJ understands the return type of it. If you wish to give it a try then you can use `0.10.1-SNAPSHOT` from [Geb's snapshot repo](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/intro.html#snapshot_repository). The way you pass a base navigator and parameters to a module has changed, see [the latest chapter on modules for info](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/modules.html#modules). It would be awesome if you could give it a try and tell me if by simply changing the version you get autocompletion.

Comment: WOW. Thanks, Ok - i will try and report here.

Comment: Autocompletion in modules works fine with this Snapshot in IntelliJ! But i had some difficulties with connecting of this Snapshot. Maybe it's too raw for now... Also Idea showed me "Method 'waitFor' is not implemented" for Pages and Modules...  But anyway, thanks. I am already waiting for a new release! )